# Hbase: Total number of rows in a table

Tags: hbase

Is there an easy way of finding total number of rows in htable? I don't want to scan all the regions for that. If number of rows is stored somewhere in metadata of table or region then that will be great.

Answer (score 8):

You could run `count '<table_name>'` in the HBase shell.

Comment: This is not helpful for tables with a real size as it runs a serial process to 'scan all the regions'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking [RowCounter](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#rowcounter)? I dont think there is any metadata information related to counts. Would be interested to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something new after HBase introduced co-processors there is no fast way to determine the exact number of rows in a table.  depending on your key structure, you might be able to get a rough estimate

Answer (score 0):

You can use coprocessors introduced in Hbase which gives the response in seconds.Use the AggregationClient to get the total count